# Generate random fake geographical data with conditions

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to think what is the best way to generate a fake map with some fake data that is random but follows some conditions. For example I want to have 8 dots east of the "Deleng" river and 12 west. I want the mean of the color to be higher east than west. Other than that, I want the points to be random

This is the code I have right now:

```
set.seed(7102015)

gen.schools <- function(n.schools){
  School.long <- rnorm(n = n.schools, mean = 21.7672, sd = 0.025)
  School.lat <- rnorm(n = n.schools, mean = 58.8471, sd = 0.025)
  School.VAM <- rnorm(n = n.schools, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  Schools <- data.frame(School.lat, School.long, School.VAM)
  return(Schools)
}

district.map <- gen.schools(n.schools = 20)

library(leaflet)
# Create a continuous palette function
pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "RdYlBu",
  domain = district.map$School.VAM
)

leaflet() %>% addTiles("http://opengeofiction.net/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png") %>%
  setView(lng = 21.7672, lat = 58.8471, 13) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = district.map, lat = ~School.lat, lng =~School.long, 
                   fillColor = ~pal(School.VAM),
                   stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1) %>% 
  addLegend(position = "topright",
            pal = pal, values = district.map$School.VAM,
            title = "Performance Index",
            opacity = 1
  )
```

If using the river as a condition is not possible, can I superimpose a fine lat long grid to this fake map so I can pick the points by hand?

Thanks!